# How to change a:hover background color?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have tried `a:hover` and `.nav > li > a:hover` but it will not change the background color. Alternatively I tried `.nav a:hover` and that worked but immediately after clicking, the background changed to the color you see in the image. So I also tried `.nav a:visited`, but that didn't change anything.

Any ideas?

[image: what it looks like when hovered]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class = "supporting">
         <div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class="header">
               <h1 class = "logo"></h1>
               <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                  <li>
                     <a href="#">Projects</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#">Photography</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#">blog</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
               <h1>i'm maria</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "work">
         <div class = "container-fluid">
            <h1>work</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  font-family:;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-top:0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav > li > a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.header h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
}

.header .nav {
  padding-left:10px;
}

.work h1 {
    border-left: 0px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    left:50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:;
  }

.supporting h1 {
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:white;

  }
.supporting .container-fluid {
  background-image: url("img/photo-top.jpg");
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  top: 0;

}

.work .container-fluid {
  height:500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white);
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
}

div.container-fluid {
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: _"Any ideas...?"_ - go read up on what CSS Specificity is, and use your browser dev tools to see what is going on.

Comment: Do you want that when hover on link then bg color change...?

Comment: i want the background to be transparent on hover

Comment: Have messed around on dev tools, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

CSS

***on hover***

```
.nav li a:focus,
.nav li a:hover
{
background-color:red/*desired color*/
}
```

***on hover on active element***

```
.nav li.active a,
.nav li.active a:hover,
.nav li.active a:focus
{
background-color:Red;/*desired color*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```css
  html, body {
  font-family:;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-top:0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav > li > a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color:black;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.header h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
}

.header .nav {
  padding-left:10px;
}

.work h1 {
    border-left: 0px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    left:50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:;
  }

.supporting h1 {
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:white;

  }
.supporting .container-fluid {
  background-image: url("img/photo-top.jpg");
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  top: 0;

}

.work .container-fluid {
  height:500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white);
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
}

div.container-fluid {
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "supporting">
<div class = "container-fluid">
<div class="header">
<h1 class = "logo"></h1>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li>
<a href="#">Projects</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Photography</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">blog</a>
</li>
</ul>
<h1>i'm maria</h1>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class = "work">
<div class = "container-fluid">
<h1>work</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok that i know but i made some extra changes so you can easily understand. but in this snippet what you want to change....?